# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand not int

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I am comparing 2 files and remove the duplicates from the second file. But throwing error

2 files. Need to add one number at last of first line and append into file2.txt. But if the modified part is already there then file2 remain untouched

```
import re
import sys
file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]
rx = r'(?<=:)(\d*)$'
with open(file1,'r') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()
    with open(file2, 'a+') as fw:
        x = fw.write(re.sub(rx , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1) if len(x.group(1)) else "0", fh_n, 1, re.M))
        if x not in file2:
            fw.write(x)
```

file1.txt

```
python 2.7:
  Java 1.8:

python test.py file1.txt file2.txt
```

Expected Out even after so many execution

```
 python 2.7:0
      Java 1.8:
```

I got the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 15, in 
    if x not in file2:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int

Comment: If you're familiar with C, then you're familiar with the idea of a file descriptor. That's what you get when you do `open()` in python - not a string, but a file descriptor. To actually get a string out of that file, you have to `.read()` it somehow. That said, I'm confused from your description what the line `if fw not in file2:` is supposed to accomplish in the first place.

Comment: updated the code, now i am getting TypeError

Comment: Do you have a question? Is there something that you don't understand in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the content of file2 to search x into it. You code should be:

```
import re
import sys
import os
file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]
rx = r'(?<=:)(\d*)$'
with open(file1,'r') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()
    with open(file2, 'a+') as fw:
        x = re.sub(rx , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1) if len(x.group(1)) else "0", fh_n, 1, re.M)
        fw.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)      # seek to the beginning of file before reading
        if x not in fw.read():
            fw.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)  # seek to end of file before writing
            fw.write(x)
```

I have added `seek` calls, because they are required between read and write operations.

Comment: what is os.SEEK_SET Sir, How you got this?  How to improve the coding skills, Can you enlighten.

Comment: @Mous: time to learn the Python documentation ;-) The reference for the `file.seek` method are [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) - search for `seek` in the page. Not that I do not want to tell you, but Python doc will be better that anything I could write myself...